# A difficulty in understanding the definition of a bounded operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

[image]

I do not understand the last line in this picture, why the smallest ball in $H_{2}$ which contains $AS_{1}$ has radius $||A||$, could anyone clarify this for me please?

Comment: Do you not recognize that this is defining "$||A||$", or do you not recognize why this agrees or disagrees with some other definition of "$||A||$"?

Comment: why this agrees with the definition of the norm given here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521695/the-difference-between-2-definitions-of-the-norm-of-an-operator/2521785#2521785 ?@EricTowers

Comment: Could you prove that $\|A\| = \inf \{ c \geq 0 \mid \forall x \in H_1: \|Ax\| \leq c \|x\|\}$?

Comment: @Idonotknow Maybe take a look at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171259/equivalent-definitions-of-the-operator-norm)?

Comment: Nitpick:  The answer you cite does not contain the norm of an operator (explicitly).  (end nitpick)  The question it answers does, and both definitions in that question agree with the definition in this question.

Comment: why "both definitions in that question agree with the definition in this question", could you explain please?